# I want to move a 30 amp RV plug wired with 10 gauge. Can I splice the wires to add an additional 25 feet?

Tags: electrical

I currently have a 30 amp RV, which is 25 feet from the breaker box wired with 10 gauge wire. I want to move it another 25 feet. Can I splice these wires onto another 25 foot wire and move the plug?

Comment: Yes, you can splice wires. You'll need a box at the splice, though. Many people replace the wiring entirely to avoid such a box.

Comment: If this is an extension cord type situation, splice it in any safe manner. If it's building wiring, you'll need to use a box like everyone else is saying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but the splice must be in an accessible junction box.

If possible I would like not to splice and use a new cable.  Fewer connections to have problems, but a splice done right will be okay.

Comment: For the pedants in the room, is there not some super-expensive, outlandish, foolish, but technically feasible method for splicing without a box?

Comment: @popham  There is a way of doing it inside of walls without a box, but not all locations allow it.  Being cheaper than a two buck box and 15 cents of wire nuts, I do not know.  Somehow I do not think this is happening in the dining room where a box might not look nice.

Comment: If this is a portable cable, no box needed as code doesn't apply. I.e. if the asker is just extending an extension cord, they can do so safely using inline splices. Soldering and two sizes of glue lined heat shrink is a reasonable way to do it, for example. (I think this is probably moving a receptacle, but the wording is just vague enough to cast doubt.)

Comment: @KMJ  Did not think of that and you are right.  Should add an answer about extension cords.